# onclick for span tag not working in Android browser

Tags: android, html

Does below works in Android browsers? It is working find in Google Chrome on Android mobiles but not with Android native browser.

```
<span onclick="alert('hello')" >
```

If it don't work in android then will  is replacement?

Comment: Didn't understand your question. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Math onclick function is not executing when touch on span tag in android browser

Comment: The double-quotes inside double-quotes might be upsetting the HTML parser. Try using single-quotes inside the javascript, e.g. `<span onclick="alert('hello')">`.

Comment: corrected it, but what is the solution?

Comment: Did changing the quotes not fix it? Maybe if could you post a more complete sample that could give people more ideas.